# Multiutil: CRMMS0093E Error: Exception: CRMMD1881E Invalid Credentials

Tags: clearquest

### Some information

Site REPL2_SH is created from REPL1_SH.
These is no issue with synchronizaiton of schema repostiory MASTR.
The issue is for user database OS.

### AT site REPL2_SH

I am providing correct password still the import to database throwing below error. I am also not able to login to CQ client but I am able to login to user administration with admin id and password.

```
$ multiutil syncreplica  -import  -rec -clan ASIA -user admin -pass xxxxxx -fam OS -site REPL2_SH -sclass cq2_sh
Multiutil: CRMMS0093E Error: Exception: CRMMD1881E Invalid Credentials: Either the login name or the password is incorrect.
```

when I check for the replica in schema repository, it says

```
$  multiutil lsreplica -clan ASIA -user admin -pass xxxxx -fam MASTR -site REPL2_SH -long | grep OS

Name: REPL2_SH; Clan: ASIA; Family: MASTR; Host: xxxx; Status: NORMAL, NOT CONNECTED; Description: ; Block Size: 4096; Block Threshold: 1024
Name: REPL2_SH; Clan: ASIA; Family: OS; Host: xxxx; Status: NORMAL, NOT CONNECTED; Description: ; Block Size: 4096; Block Threshold: 1024
```

when I check for the replica in user database, it says

```
$  multiutil lsreplica -clan ASIA -user admin -pass xxxxx -fam OS -site REPL2_SH -long
Multiutil: CRMMS0093E Error: Exception: CRMMD1881E Invalid Credentials: Either the login name or the password is incorrect.
```

Any comments on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You renamed your profile the other day; I'd suggest creating a copy and reverting one to the previous name. Then try again and see if you're still having issues.

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. I am really not sure what is happening . It should work.